# How change and see button background image few millisecond?

Tags: android, android-layout

When i click on a button i want to change, during 500ms, the button backgourndimage and do a short animation. I've done a code, but i can't see the relsult, the animation is ok but the clicked image button don't appear.

the defalut button image is "boutton_a.png"
the clicked button image is "button_a_ok.png"

here's the onclick button code:

```
            if (Button04.getText().equals(Reponse)){
                    Button01.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boutton_a_ok);
                    AnimationSet set=new AnimationSet(true);
                    Animation animation=new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,10,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,10);
                    animation.setDuration(100);
                    set.addAnimation(animation);
                    Button01.startAnimation(set);
            }else{
                    Button01.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.boutton_a_nok);
                    AnimationSet set=new AnimationSet(true);
                    Animation animation=new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,10,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,10);
                    animation.setDuration(100);
                    set.addAnimation(animation);
                    Button04.startAnimation(set);
            }
```

How can i do ?

EDIT: I've post all the code, because there's 2 backgroundressources differents

Comment: add timer and run method set the background image

Answer (score 0):

You can change the button background on button click by creating a drawable for different button states from xml. here is example

```
<selector 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

Save this file in the drawable folder as new_button.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/new_button" />
```

Comment: I've post all the code. In fact i want to change the backgroundressource depending the string 'reponse' and do the animation.

Answer (score 0):

put this file in your resources foldr as "rotate.xml"
res/anim/rotate.xml

and use this class to animate

```
public class DownloadButton extends Button
{
    private String state = "Normal";
    public DownloadButton( Context context )
        {
            super(context);
        }
    public DownloadButton( Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
        {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
    public DownloadButton( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle )
        {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }
    public void setState(String state)
        {
            this.state = state;
            if (this.state.equals("Downloading"))
                {
                    ButtonAnimate();
                }
            else if(this.state.equals("Waiting"))
                {
                    setToWaiting(); 
                }
            else
                {
                    clearAnimation();
                }
        }
    private void setToWaiting()
        {
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.waiting);
        }
    public void ButtonAnimate()
        {
            this.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MediaSingleton.getInstance().getContext(), R.anim.rotate));
        }
    public String getState()
        {
            return state;
        }
}
```

and use this button in your layout like this

```
<com.yourpackage.DownloadButton
    android:id="@+id/Downloadbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/download"
    />
```

and use this animation like this

```
Button button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.yourbtnid);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.downloading);
button.setState("Downloading");
```

you have done your animation good luck